# Are there any performance gains by moving logic from the view to the viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Obviously there is lot's to gain by moving structure and logic into a viewmodel. How much is perhaps a matter of taste.

One big plus for the developer of keeping logic in cshtml is you don't have to recompile the whole project.

But are there any performance gains for the user to consider?

**Clarfication**

My viewmodels contain logic for example replacing \n with 
 and returning HtmlStrings, combining booleans, comparing UTC-dates. But no foreaching of comments, since there is structure in there, albeit very little.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the logic the main benefit would be to the user and how fast the page displays.

Theoretically MVC shouldn't have any logic in the view, but we all know that on a pragmatic approach there may be some in order to expedite certain functionality in the View.

What is annoying though is when developers embed, large scripts in the View, which can really hamper the user experience especially over a slow connection.

On the whole though the biggest bugbear for web page performance is data access. A decent data cacheing process will have a vast effect on performance, as it cuts down all of those database queries.

Comment: I get you. But C#-code does not run slower just because it's in a view rather than in the precompiled dll? (after first view after poolrecycle of course)